# Precise drag and drop contentplaceholder into contenteditable using js

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, contenteditable, contentplaceholder

**Setup:**
- contenteditable div (as textarea) containing text 
-  drag container containing draggable elements (called placeholders).

**HTML:** drop container

```
<div id="contentBox" class="editableBox" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

**HTML:** drag container

```
<div id="placeholderBox">
    <span class="btnEditable" contenteditable="false">test1</span>
    <span class="btnEditable" contenteditable="false">test2</span>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
    $("body").on("mousedown", ".btnEditable", function(){
        $(this).selectText();
    }).on("dragend", ".btnEditable", function(e){
        $(".editableBox")
            .find("span:not(.btnEditable)").addClass("btnEditable").attr("contenteditable",false)
            .removeAttr("style").html($(e.currentTarget).html());
    });
});
```

**Goal:**
The desired functionality is to drag any placeholder and drop it into the contenteditable on a precise text position. In a second step I want to use an additional function to replace these dropped placeholders with some dynamic content.

**Problems:**
The first step is done and works perfectly in Firefox 32 (maybe other versions work as well) and IE 11.
But I have several problems getting it work in Chrome (my version is 37) and IE 9/10.

Chrome

1. Chrome converts contenteditable content to string having "
2. <s>Chrome puts dropped content into own [span] container</s> *fixed already*
3. redragging an element has no "dragend" event anymore, so (2) doesn't work with redragged elements

IE

1. Doesn't work in IE < 9
2. IE 9 + 10: redragging placeholder clones it instead of moving it to new position

**Sample**
Just take a look at my sample: **[jsFiddle: Sample for precise drag and drop functionality](http://jsfiddle.net/cevf8zwh/6/)**

Thanks everybody.